# one dimensional SDE with zero drift

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

I was trying to prove that the solution $X$ to the one dimensional SDE
$dX_t = \sigma(X_t)dW_t$
(where $\sigma$ is a real valued Borel measurable function, $W$ is a 1d Brownian Motion) cannot explode, i.e. $S= \infty$ a.s., where $S= \inf\{t\geq 0: X_t \notin \mathbb{R}\}$.
I was able to show that $\{\int^{t \min S} _0\sigma^2(X_s)ds= \infty\}$ has probability 0 for all $t\geq 0$ (using time changed brownian motion and law of iterated logarithm to arrive at a contradiction to almost sure path continuity of the solution in the extended real). How do I procede from here to conclude that $P\{S= \infty\}=1$? I was thinking of using Ito's isometry $E[\int^{t \min S} _0\sigma^2(X_s)ds]= E[(\int^{t \min S} _0\sigma(X_s)dW_s)^2]$ $\Rightarrow X_{t \min S} - X_0= \int^{t \min S} _0\sigma(X_s)dW_s \in \mathbb{R}$ a.s., but the expectation of the Ito integral could be unbounded.

This is an exercise from Karatzas & Shreve

Thanks!

Comment: I have seen something like this in connection with Feller's test for explosions, have you heard of this?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I know about Feller's test. I would like to prove the result directly though.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear this is 5.3 problem from Shreve-Karatzas. It *assumes* that $dX_t = \sigma(X_t)dW_t$ has a weak solution up to explosion time $S$ and it asks to show $S=\infty$ a.s..

From problem 3.4.11 in Shreve-Karatzas, we have that $\int_{0}^{T}\sigma(X_{s})dW_{s}$ is only defined if we have $\int_{0}^{T}\sigma(X_{s})^{2}ds<\infty$. (This follows using time-change to Brownian motion and its iterated law of logarithm.)

By the definition of explosion up to $S_{n}:=\inf\{t\geq : |X_{t}|\geq n\}$ we have

$$P[\int_{0}^{t\wedge S_{n}}\sigma(X_{s})^{2}ds<\infty]=1.$$

and so we split

$$1=P[\int_{0}^{t\wedge S_{n}}\sigma(X_{s})^{2}ds<\infty,S<\infty]+P[\int_{0}^{t\wedge S_{n}}\sigma(X_{s})^{2}ds<\infty,S=\infty]$$

take limit

$$=P[\int_{0}^{t\wedge S}\sigma(X_{s})^{2}ds<\infty,S<\infty]+P[\int_{0}^{t}\sigma(X_{s})^{2}ds<\infty,S=\infty]$$

the first term contains $X_{S}=\infty$

$$=P[\int_{0}^{t\wedge S}\sigma(X_{s})^{2}ds<\infty,X_{S}=\infty,S<\infty]+P[\int_{0}^{t}\sigma(X_{s})^{2}ds<\infty,S=\infty].$$

However, from problem 3.4.11, this is not possible, and so the first probability is zero and we are left with

$$1=P[\int_{0}^{t}\sigma(X_{s})^{2}ds<\infty,S=\infty],$$

which implies $P[S=\infty]=1$.